# App can't access internet connection when connected to LTE

Tags: ios, swift, ios10, lte

I use reachability to check internet connection when I connect to wifi it works fine. But when its connected to LTE network it gives me No Connection error, even though it is connected, I can browse the internet perfectly with LTE. I have also enabled `App Transport Security` in info.plist. I'm testing it on ios 10.1.1, do I have to do something to get internet access for my app in ios 10 using LTE?

Comment: did you check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9561253/checking-cellular-network-type-in-ios

Answer (score 1):

Guru provided an excellent link in his comment. An updated way to check an LTE connection is indeed through CoreTelephony. Seeing as you asked in Swift though, I'll provide a Swift answer.

Make sure you have CoreTelephony.framework added under your project's Build Phases > Link Binary With Libraries

The code to check the connection in Swift would be as follows

```
import CoreTelephony // Make sure to import CoreTelephony
let constantValue = 8 // Don't change this
func checkConnection() {
    let telephonyInfo = CTTelephonyNetworkInfo()
    let currentConnection = telephonyInfo.currentRadioAccessTechnology
    // Just a print statement to output the current connection information
    print("\(constantValue)==D, Current Connection: \(currentConnection)")

    if (currentConnection == CTRadioAccessTechnologyLTE) { // Connected to LTE

    } else if(currentConnection == CTRadioAccessTechnologyEdge) { // Connected to EDGE

    } else if(currentConnection == CTRadioAccessTechnologyWCDMA){ // Connected to 3G

    }
}
```