# How to check network 2G or 3G in IOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, ios5, ios6

I want to check if the device has a 2G or 3G connection.

I used Reachability class for network connection check.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8122170/how-do-i-know-whether-my-iphone-ipad-is-connected-to-2g-or-3g

Comment: you should refer this link...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9561253/checking-cellular-network-type-in-ios

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In iOS 7 Apple provided a new way to get it.

Please read [this link](http://www.objc.io/issue-5/iOS7-hidden-gems-and-workarounds.html). The "Know your Radio" section.

The basic idea is to use the new

> currentRadioAccessTechnology

added to the CTTelephonyNetworkInfo class. If you want to get notified everytime the connection changes you can listen for:

> CTRadioAccessTechnologyDidChangeNotification

Heres a code snippet took from the provided link:

```
CTTelephonyNetworkInfo *telephonyInfo = [CTTelephonyNetworkInfo new];
NSLog(@"Current Radio Access Technology: %@", telephonyInfo.currentRadioAccessTechnology);
[NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter addObserverForName:CTRadioAccessTechnologyDidChangeNotification 
                                            object:nil 
                                             queue:nil 
                                        usingBlock:^(NSNotification *note) 
{
    NSLog(@"New Radio Access Technology: %@", telephonyInfo.currentRadioAccessTechnology);
}];
```

I hope this helps you.

Comment: When you link to articles, please also cite the most important parts because links tend to become dead after some time. Also, you might add this information to [another question as well](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8122170/how-do-i-know-whether-my-iphone-ipad-is-connected-to-2g-or-3g).

Comment: @pdrcabrod it will return --> Current Radio Access Technology: (null)